# Quadratures of Romberg and Gauss - number of nodes and function evaluation

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I am asked to numerically evaluate an integral using the quadrature of Romberg and Gauss and to give the number of nodes and the number of evaluation of the function.
I found the value of the integral using both methods.

The thing that i don't get is that I have the number of nodes, but how can I find the number of times we evaluate the function ? I thought that they were the same.

Thanks

Comment: It's the same except if for some nodes you don't need to evaluate the function, e.g. if you can exploit a symmetry, or if the value at some node has a value like 1 or 0 that doesn't require numerical work to evaluate precisely.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is what I thought but the way the question was asked got me confused !